# How to plot frequencies of a categorical 0-1 variable with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a categorical variable, Outcome, which has values 0 and 1.
I would like to plot the frequency of Outcome=1 per year and, at each year, stratify by gender.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Outcome, fill=interaction(GENDER, Year)))+
geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width=0.4), aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))
```

However, by doing so I obtain two separate croups of columns, one for Outcome = 0 and one for Outcome = 1. I would like to keep the Outcome = 1 column only.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply plot the `subset` of `dataset` where `Outcome` equals 1:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(subset(dataset, Outcome == 0), aes(x = Year, fill = GENDER)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
set.seed(1)
dataset <- data.frame(Outcome = sample(0:1, 500, TRUE),
                      GENDER = rep(rep(c("Male", "Female"), 50), 5),
                      Year = rep(2010:2014, each = 100))

 head(dataset)
#>   Outcome GENDER Year
#> 1       0   Male 2010
#> 2       1 Female 2010
#> 3       0   Male 2010
#> 4       0 Female 2010
#> 5       1   Male 2010
#> 6       0 Female 2010
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By doing so, I will have the frequencies calculated only on that subset (denominator will be length of the subset Outcome==1). I would like to plot the frequencies of Outcome==1 per year per gender in the whole dataset instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset` in the ggplot call for the data.

So this should work to plot just the values for Outcome equal to 1 (assuming Outcome is numeric):

```
ggplot(subset(dataset, Outcome == 1), aes(x=Outcome, fill=interaction(GENDER, Year)))
+ geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width=0.4), aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By doing so, I will have the frequencies calculated only on that subset (denominator will be length of the subset Outcome==1). I would like to plot the frequencies of Outcome==1 per year per gender in the whole dataset instead.